# how to get accurate time duration in html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to code for a test get people's tap frequency with music.
Here is something without the music, but people can tap on their laptop touch pad to get the data. However, the data seems not accurate enough, for example it at least be  200 milliseconds. and when we steady tap it, it offered a quite variable result. someone can tell me how to improve it?

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html onclick="myFunction()">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title>Click</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      inner = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
      if(inner === ""){
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = Date();
      }
      else{
        var curr = new Date();
        console.log(curr);
        var past = new Date(inner);
        console.log(inner);
        console.log(past);
        var gap = curr.getTime() - past.getTime();
        console.log(gap);
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = curr;
        var gapText = document.getElementById("gap").innerHTML;
        gapText = gapText + gap + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("gap").innerHTML = gapText;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <div><text>The current time is </text><text id="time"></text></div>
    <div><text>The tap durations are (milliseconds):</text></div>
    <div><text id="gap"></text></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this and seems to be working. By the way, you can use a variable instead of parsing the contents of your element every time.

Comment: Seems like it will greatly be dependent on the hardware touchpad the user is using.

Answer (score 0):

I also got a large variable of time differences with your code on a MacBook Pro running in Chrome. Then I refactored your code and got significantly better performance, generally within ~30ms. Matthew Herbst is right, hardware is going to play a factor, but I think there are ways to improve performance. My refactored code is below, but a couple of observations:

1. Take out all the console.logs. They don't affect performance too much, but when you're worried about a handful of milliseconds, they do.
2. Only interact with the DOM when you absolutely have to. For instance, you're going to the DOM to get the last timestamp, in order to calculate the current value. Save it in a variable, it's faster.

Here's my code, let me know how well it works for you. Hope this helps.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html onclick="myFunction()">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <title>Click</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    var newTime;
    function myFunction() {

      if (newTime === undefined){
        newTime = new Date();
        // This will only run once
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newTime;
      }
      else{
        // Here I'm not getting values from the DOM. I'm saving the value as a variable. 
        var oldTime = newTime;
        newTime = new Date();
        var gap = newTime.getTime() - oldTime.getTime();
        var gapText = gap + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("gap").innerHTML = gapText;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <div><text>The current time is </text><text id="time"></text></div>
    <div><text>The tap durations are (milliseconds):</text></div>
    <div><text id="gap"></text></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <script>
    var pastTime
    function myFunction() {
      var time = new Date();
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;
      if(pastTime !== undefined){
        var gap = time.getTime() - pastTime.getTime();
        document.getElementById("gap").innerHTML = gap;
      }
      pastTime = time;
    }
    </script>
    <div><text>The current time is </text><text id="time"></text></div>
    <div><text>The tap durations are (milliseconds):</text></div>
    <div><text id="gap"></text></div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: yes , thank you, but i still need to test how accurate it is